# Page PG_referenced vs PG_active bit?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, operating-system, virtual-memory

I was reading about pages and memory allocaitons and found:

`PG_referenced` and `PG_active` but it's not clear to me what's the difference at all?
I know that PG_active is set when acessing the page and cleared every some time. but how is that different from `PG_referenced`, how can one be 1 and other be 0 or both share same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specific to Linux implementation. There are two LRU lists for the page cache that pages jump between: active and inactive. The `PG_active` bit tells you if the page is currently on the active list or not. Look at [this function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.0/source/mm/swap.c#L597) from `mm/swap.c`:

```
/*
 * Mark a page as having seen activity.
 *
 * inactive,unreferenced    ->  inactive,referenced
 * inactive,referenced      ->  active,unreferenced
 * active,unreferenced      ->  active,referenced
 *

void mark_page_accessed(struct page *page)
```

This function comment explains it well. Any page that needs to be marked as accessed makes a transition from one of those states on the left (e.g. "inactive, unreferenced") to the states on the right (e.g. "inactive, reference"). When an inactive but referenced page is accessed again, it should jump to the active list, have its active bit set, but have its referenced bit cleared.

A page that is active and referenced is safest from being kicked out of memory, whereas inactive unreferenced pages are first in line for being kicked out. The page replacement algorithm will move pages off the active list to the inactive list as needed to keep a certain ratio of pages on each list and to keep a certain amount of free pages available for the OS.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't answer my question, I asked what is `PG_referenced` how it's different from active, when it's set and why not just create active with 4 levels. What referenced here means at all...

Comment: The difference is `PG_referenced` is also set by hardware, in addition to being manually set by the OS (like in `mark_page_accessed()`). So the Linux kernel developers decided that instead of using one single LRU list and only relying on that single referenced bit, they'd use two lists. They use `PG_active` for their own bookkeeping to determine which list the page is on and they use the `PG_referenced` bit to see how hot it is on that list. It's implementation specific. They could have decided to create 4 levels with 4 different bits, but apparently they didn't.

Comment: When you see "unreferenced -> referenced" in the kernel comment, that's a case where `PG_referenced` is set during `mark_page_accessed()`. If hardware sees that an unreferenced page is accessed, it can also set the bit. Therefore, a page table entry could have any combination of `PG_active` or `PG_referenced` set. The kernel comment covers all 4 combinations.

Comment: So in other words `PG_referenced` is TOTALLY equivalent to `PG_active` right? (both serve exactly same job and we can call them active1 and active2) Still it's not clear why in the first -> we updated the reference and not the active field.

Comment: Functionally, they're almost equivalent, just two bits that are used to determine how "hot" a page is. But the minor nuance is important. `PG_referenced` can get set by hardware. And `PG_active` tells you which list the page is on. Implementation wise, they could have made `PG_referenced` tell you which list its on, and `PG_active` would be "how hot on the list" it is. If you designed your own OS you could make it like that.

Comment: To understand the kernel comment, it's helpful to read about the [Clock page replacement algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm#Clock). The general idea is that, in a single list implementation, the clock hand (or the selection mechanism) circles through a list of pages looking to kick out pages. Each page gets a second chance if a single bit is set (e.g. the `PG_referenced` bit). The Linux Kernel version has two lists and within each list, each page has a second chance to stay on the list if it's `PG_referenced` bit is set.

Comment: Therefore, traditional Clock has one list, and is also called second chance policy. Linux has two lists and could be called four chance policy. A page has at most 4 chances to stay in memory if it starts out active and referenced. So the first -> that you're asking about is how to give a page on the inactive list a new second chance: by setting its `PG_referenced` bit. You give it a new second chance either by the hardware setting the bit or by someone calling `mark_page_accessed()`. Every call to `mark_page_accessed()` gives that page an additional "chance."

Comment: How can `PG_referenced` be set by hardware when it's a bit in the `.flags` of `struct page`? `struct page` is just a software abstraction, hardware does not know about it. Do you have an example of this behavior?

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this thread again, I found [this](https://lpc.events/event/11/contributions/896/attachments/793/1493/slides-r2.pdf) well explained slide deck made by SUSE on that exact topic. Could be worth checking out

Answer (score 0):

`PG_active` is set when the page belongs to the active list and cleared when it is in the inactive list. `PG_reference` is set when the page is referenced regardless of whether it is in the active or inactive list.