# Do cache hits count as page references in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, cpu-architecture, paging

In Linux, pages in memory have a `PG_referenced` bit which is set when there is a reference to the page. My question is, if there is a memory read/write to an address in a page and there was a cache hit for that address, will it count as a reference to that page?

Comment: Is `PG_reference` a status bit to tell the Linux the page is in use? if yes, how that has anything to do with the cache? Anyway, a hit in the cache can only happen if the virtual address can be translated to the physical address since the latter is used as the tag (though for the sole lookup in the cache, it's not, or wasn't, strictly necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Is `PG_referenced` what Linux calls the bit in the hardware page tables that the CPU updates when a page is accessed?  Or is it tracking whether a page is referenced by another kernel data structure?

---

The CPU hardware sets a bit in the page-table entry on access to **virtual** page, if it wasn't already set.  (I assume most ISAs have functionality like this to help detect less recently used pages, e.g. the OS can clear the Accessed bit on some pages, and later check to see which pages still haven't been accessed.  Without having to actually invalidate them and force a soft page fault on access.)

On x86 for example, the check (for whether to "trap" to an internal microcode assist to atomically set the [Accessed and/or Dirty bit in the PTE and higher levels in the page directory](https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging#Page_Directory)) is **based on the TLB entry caching the PTE**.

This is unrelated to D-cache or I-cache hit or miss for the **physical** address.

Updating the Accessed and/or Dirty bits works even for pages set to be uncacheable, I think.

Comment: Re: *"Is `PG_referenced` what Linux calls the bit in the hardware page tables that the CPU updates when a page is accessed? Or is it tracking whether a page is referenced by another kernel data structure?"* - Neither of those. `PG_referenced` is a `struct page` flag (unrelated to the "dirty" or "accessed" bits of PTEs) used for LRU purposes to decide when to move pages between active and inactive lists.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Thanks.  Do you want to write an answer about what `PG_referenced` actually is?  I think the question of whether (data/instruction) cache hits are relevant to hardware page-table bits is an interesting [cpu-architecture] question to answer, so I'd like to keep that in an answer somewhere, perhaps on another question if there is one.  The actual question here almost asks that, but not quite :/

Comment: I was hesitant to add an answer because 1) there are already some Q&A talking about this ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68447964/page-pg-referenced-vs-pg-active-bit)) so maybe linking to that is better; 2) I do not actually have an answer to OP's main question because although I know the purpose of that page flag, I do not now exactly *when* it is set. I would need to do more research, which right now I am not able to. Feel free to incorporate my comments in your answer if you like.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Fair enough, thanks.  Probably fine to just leave things as they are, assuming nobody nukes these valuable comments.  I'd assume that the hardware Accessed bit as described in my answer is what Linux uses (somehow) to get an input to its LRU tracking, maybe scanning for it at some times and calling `mark_page_accessed`.